# FBA and MemberShipProvider

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, membership-provider

Do we always need to extend web app when using FBA?

I know it seems a silly question, but I can't find a straight answer.

EDIT: SharePoint 2010

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2007 or 2010? Trevor's answer below is right if you're using 2010. In SharePoint 2007, you would need to extend the web application if you wanted to support more than one authentication provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use FBA and Windows Auth on the same Web Application without extending it.  The Web App must be Claims-based, however.

Comment: thanks. So if I just want FBA authentication for internet users, I don't need to extend, IIS doing the job for public URL?

Comment: Yes, just enable FBA, configure the Web App's web.config, the STS, and CA web.config (optional, but I'd recommend it).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've done (even if I don't understand why in CA, because it ties your entire SharePoint with the same version of assembly).